# Can I write a function in php with multiple optional arguments but at least one HAS to be used?

Tags: php

I'm still new to PHP, so I wonder if it is possible to write a function with several optional parameters but at least one of those needs to be used?

Something like

```
function my_func($arg1="", $arg2="", $arg3=""){
//at least one of the args should be set
}
```

or do I just test within in the function and return false if none was set?

Comment: You can set default values for 2 of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add code yourself which you can always enhance to check (for example) only 1 argument should be passed.  Just throw `InvalidArgumentException` with some description if the validation fails...

```
function my_func($arg1="", $arg2="", $arg3=""){
    if ( empty($arg1) && empty($arg2) && empty($arg3) ) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("At least one parameter must be passed");
    }
}
```

You may want to set the default values to `null` if `""` is a valid value, but then change the test to `is_null($arg1)` etc. as `""` is also empty.

Answer (score 2):

You should check it manually. Like this

```
function my_func($arg1="", $arg2="", $arg3=""){
 if (!$arg1 && !$arg2 && !$arg3) {
   throw new Exception('None of arguments is set!'); //Or just return false, depend on your siruation
 }
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to explicitly check it within the function body, but you can streamline it a little by pushing all your variables to an array, and filter the empty values out. When there are no results left after filtering, you know none was passed.

```php
function my_func($arg1 = null, $arg2 = null, $arg3 = null) {
    if (count(array_filter([$arg1, $arg2, $arg3])) === 0) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('At least one argument must be used');
    }
    echo 'It works!'."\n";
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/i8qT0

Comment: no need to count `if (array_filter([$arg1, $arg2, $arg3]) === []) {`

Comment: Using count you can alter the logic to ensure exactly 1 argument was passed, by changing it to `!== 1` instead of `=== 0`. But yes, either works - I prefer using count.